# Right to uninstall another app from device administrator app

Tags: android, admin, device

I am making a device administration app just like http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html . How can i add functionality for uninstalling app or installing another app from this app. i can uninstall the another app using intent( this will not need any device administration app , any app can perform using this) but user will get a prompt for uninstalling app. since its  device administration app so i want to uninstall app without any prompt.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it's possible to silently uninstall an app that is an active device administrator. i believe that's an intended feature of being a device admin.